# Requirements for Twilight Bow

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild, amiibo

I have the Zelda Amiibo that drops the Twilight Bow in *Breath of the Wild* for the Switch. I know it's a rare drop and that I can use the save/reload technique to keep trying until I get it.

Are there any special requirements that I need to meet before I can get the Twilight Bow from the Amiibo? I think I read somewhere that I first need to beat the four divine beats, or at least one of them, before I can get the drop and I haven't beaten any yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Twilight Bow](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Twilight_Bow) article on the *Zelda* wiki you need to defeat at least one of the Divine Beasts before you can obtain the Twilight Bow from the Amiibo

> The Twilight Bow only appears after Link has completed and freed one of the Divine Beasts, thus will not randomly spawn until Link has completed at least one of the Divine Beast dungeons

Also, for what it's worth, make sure you do have the correct Zelda Amiibo. As listed on the [Amiibo wiki](http://orcz.com/Breath_of_the_Wild:_Amiibo_Items), there are two versions of Zelda:

- Super Smash Brothers, which does spawn the Twilight Bow
- Breath of the Wild, which does not spawn the Twilight Bow

I'm not sure if this applies to your case, but may be applicable to others

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds :p

Comment: OK thanks, good to know. I will defeat the first divine beast, Vah Ruta, before attempting to unlock the Twilight Bow.

Comment: The divine beasts can be fought in any order, there is no "first" one. Vah Ruta is just often the first one people do because it's the closest to Kakariko

Answer (score 1):

According to the fandom wiki page for the [Twilight Bow](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Twilight_Bow):

> It can be obtained randomly from Treasure Chests summoned by using the
>   amiibo Rune and the Zelda amiibo of the Super Smash Bros. series. The
>   Twilight Bow only appears after Link has completed and freed one of
>   the Divine Beasts, thus will not randomly spawn until Link has
>   completed at least one of the Divine Beast dungeons.